# Doubt in a part of a proof.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional spaces and let $A:V\to W$ and $G:W\to V$ are linear maps.

Then, look the following statements,

$(1)$ $AG$ is idempotent and $V=R(G)+N(A)$

$(2)$ $GA$ is idempotent and $N(GA)=N(A)$.

We have to prove that $(1)\implies (2)$. 
How we can do this??

Comment: I  could not prove that $GA$ is idempotent using the given information even.

Comment: I assume $R(G)$ is image, aka. $G(W)$ or $\operatorname{im}G$, and $N(A)$ is the nullspace, aka. kernel or $\ker A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in V$. As $V = R(G) + N(A)$, we may write $v = Gw + v'$, where $Av' = 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
  (GA)^2v &= GAGA(Gw + v')\\
          &= GAGAGw\\
          &= GAGw\\
          &= G(AGw + Av')\\
          &= GA(Gw + v')\\
          &= GAv 
\end{align*}
Hence $(GA)^2 = GA$.

We obviously have $N(A)\subseteq N(GA)$, so suppose $v \in N(GA)$. Write $v = Gw + v'$ with $Av' = 0$. Then 
\begin{align*}
  0 &= AGAv\\
    &= AGAGw\\
    &= AGw\\
    &= A(Gw + v')\\
    &= Av
\end{align*}
Hence $v \in N(A)$ and therefore $N(GA) = N(A)$.